# JQUERY cannot update input box value

Tags: jquery

OK I give up,m tea break time, why can I see the alert with the value I want, but I cannot update the value in the input box on page

With the code below it changes the value visibly only while the alert is there. I click OK on the alert and the value goes back to old value. If I remove the alert nothing happens, crazy ehh

```
  $("#SIC").focusout(function () {
        var sVal = $('#SIC').val();

        sVal = sVal.substr(0,sVal.indexOf(' '));

        $('#SIC').val(sVal); 

        alert(sVal);

    }).click(function (e) {

        e.stopPropagation();
        return true;
    });



@Html.TextBox("SIC", Model.SIC, new { @class = "typeahead form-control", type = "text", placeholder = "SIC code", rel = "tooltip", autocomplete = "off", title = "Enter SIC, i.e. '1630'" })
```

Comment: can you pls add  HTML code ?

Comment: Does it alert the right value you want to update the input field with?

Comment: It works: http://jsfiddle.net/Lxb6rx16/

Comment: show some html code. is it input or div?

Comment: thanks for all the assistance guys, i'm been trying the suggestions.. Looks like onfocus out code fires before the typeahead is able to set the value. This is the issue. There is a space (always) in the new value. But not the old value so the value stays the same. Updating the post now with latest ...

Comment: its like it is changing the value (it was before) but I can only see that with the alert in place. Remove the alert and its not working

Comment: It alerts with the right value, while the alert is popped up, I Can see below on the form that the new value is there, click the ok and its gone back

Answer (score 0):

your code is fine , as i see everything works fine, the only thing that confuses you is this line : `**sVal = sVal.substr(0,sVal.indexOf(' '));**`

On that line you want to get the substring of the input value , from the 0 position until the position that there is a space '  '. But if your input value does not have a space you will not get anything.

i made a jsfiddle example and i put : value="Hello World" , and as a result you get the the word Hello as a new input value.

click on the input box and then press tab to execute the event.

jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/tornado1979/997ufota/

```
$("#SIC").focusout(function () {
    var sVal = $('#SIC').val();

    sVal = sVal.substr(0,sVal.indexOf(' '));//all the secret is here.

    $('#SIC').val(sVal); 

    alert(sVal);
}).click(function (e) {

    e.stopPropagation();
    return true;
});
```

hope helps 
good luck

Comment: Its not the space, I updated my post. The value is being set but reverts back to old value. Adding the Alert allows me to see it happening. Its like I want to keep code I have but cannot because need to take alert out

Answer (score -1):

Try this -
    var sVal = $('#SIC').val();

```
    sVal = sVal.substr(0,sVal.indexOf(' '));

    $('#SIC').html(sVal);
```

---

Updated answer :

```
<input type="text" id="SIC">

$(document).ready(function() {
    alert('value will change');
    $("#textBox").val("New value")
})
```

This works.

Comment: Let me try it out. Ideally $("id").html('new html'), will replace the existing one

Comment: My code was working, so does your code, but its another issue, I updated my post above

Comment: You are absolutely correct john, i just updated my answer since .html() is used to replace text values like .innerHtml in javascript. I was just making sure to differentiate between .html() and .val() in jquery, my bad.